# Mark 2:16 - What differentiates sinners referred to as sinners as opposed to sinners not referred to as sinners?

Tags: mark, word-choice

> Mark 2:16 16 And the scribes of the Pharisees, when they saw that he was eating with sinners and tax collectors, said to his disciples, “Why does he eat with tax collectors and sinners?”

Are these people whose sins are public and yet do not publically repent of their sins? What are some examples of these types of sinners? Are we thinking of prostitutes and drunkards?

Comment: According to Rom 3:23 - we are all sinners without exception.  This question should ask what is intended by "sinners and Text Collectors" in this verse.

Answer (score 1):

Pharisees viewed sinners as any Jewish person who did not follow the Law and their own rules. My NIV Study Bible notes on Mark 2:13-16 make these comments about “sinners”:

> Notoriously evil people as well as those who refused to follow the Mosaic law as interpreted by the teachers of the law.  The term was commonly used of tax collectors, adulterers, robbers and the like.  To eat with a person was a sign of friendship.

> Not all teaches of the law were Pharisees... Although some, no doubt, were godly, most of those who came into conflict with Jesus were hypocritical, envious, rigid and formalistic.  According to Pharisaism, God’s grace extended only to those who kept his law...

> Jewish tax collectors were regarded as outcasts.  They could not serve as witnesses or as judges and were expelled from the synagogue.  In the eyes of the Jewish community their disgrace extended to their families.

Tax collectors were Jews who were working for the hated Romans.  Not only were they viewed as helping the enemy, they cheated the people they collected from by collecting more than was required and keeping the extra for themselves.  No wonder they were hated by their fellow Jews and despised by the Pharisees, viewed as being even worse than “ordinary” sinners.

Mark 2:13-17 explains that the reason Jesus was eating a meal with tax collectors and sinners is because He had just called Matthew (known as Levi, son of Alphaeus), a tax collector, to join His group of disciples.  Matthew wanted his circle of friends to meet Jesus and His disciples, hence the feast.

It is true that prostitutes and drunkards also fall under the category of sinners, but Jewish tax collectors were viewed as the lowest of the low because they stole from fellow Jews and were in league with the Romans.  That would explain why the Pharisees singled out tax collectors at this event and why they looked down upon Jesus because he associated with all sorts of sinners, including tax collectors.  Jesus made this response to the Pharisees:

> It is not the healthy who need a doctor, but the sick.  I have not come to call the righteous, but sinners (Mark 2:17).

Yes, tax collectors were sinners just like adulterers, prostitutes, drunkards and robbers.  Yet the Pharisees, because of their self-righteousness, failed to recognise they were also sinners who needed to repent, unlike Matthew.

Answer (score 1):

> **Mark 2:15-17** And it came to pass, that as he sat to eat in his house, many publicans and sinners sat down together with Jesus and his disciples: for they were many who also followed him. And the scribes and the Pharisees, seeing that he ate with publicans and sinners, said to his disiples: Why doth your master eat and drink with publicans and sinners? Jesus hearing this, saith to them: They that are well have no need of a physician, but they that are sick. For I came not to call the righteous, but sinners.

Just as some are termed "righteous" (v. 17; Mt. 1:19 ) because they are **marked by** their righteousness, even though *"there is not a righteous man"* (Rom 3:10) so also it is fitting to term those **marked by** their sin "sinners," despite the fact that *"all have sinned*" (Rom. 3:23) in a more universal sense. That is to say, *"sinners,"* as "publicans," is being used to denote a class of people within all sinners (for not all sinners are equal by any means, nor any two sins), and not as a simple adjective. For "publicans" itself did not only refer to "tax collectors," but generally those who were seen as betrayers by doing the bidding of the 'oppressors' of the people, the Romans.

Jesus uses "publican" (otherwise "tax collector") as a pejorative along with "heathen" also:

> **Matthew 18:15-17** But if thy brother shall offend against thee, go, and rebuke him between thee and him alone. If he shall hear thee, thou shalt gain thy brother. And if he will not hear thee, take with thee one or two more: that in the mouth of two or three witnesses every word may stand. And if he will not hear them: tell the church. And if he will not hear the church, **let him be to thee as the heathen and publican.**

That is, severe him from the Body, and consider him an outcast: as heathens do not follow the will of God's church, neither do these follow the will of God declared by the New Testament church. He appears to use **"publican"** here in a pejorative sense because although they were the fellow countrymen of the subjects of Rome, nevertheless, taking from the people and contributing to the Roman Empire was their occupation. That is, it was seen as a good illustration of being a **'fellow in name only,'** or here, "Christian in name only."

The Pharisees understood quite well that everyone sinned, but they were scandalized that Jesus would associate ("eat and drink") with sinners of such a public and negative reputation for being such, since it amounted, for them, to approval of their sin. But as He stated, *"They that are well have no need of a physician, but they that are sick."*

> **Luke 15:7** I say to you, that even so there shall be joy in heaven upon one sinner that repenteth, more than upon ninety-nine just who need not repentance.